# i am trying to print data using angular with html tag but it doesnt work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

`"description": "<p><s><em><strong>Plurar or singular, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, or years, it runs automatically. I've tested it on Laravel version 4.1.24.</strong></em></s></p>",`

When I am printing this with
`{{description}}` then it prints:

`<p><s><em><strong>Plurar or singular, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, or years, it runs automatically. I've tested it on Laravel version 4.1.24.</strong></em></s></p>`

I want this as:

`Plurar or singular, seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, or years, it runs automatically. I've tested it on Laravel version 4.1.24.`

Comment: can you please post a proper question

Comment: add code snippets

Comment: You should bind to html attribute for the element you want to place the description into it. [innerHtml]="description"

Comment: is there not any functionality in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it works:

```
{{!!description!!}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [innerHTML]="description">
</div>
```

Write something like this.

Answer (score 1):

To render html file you have use [innerHTML] attribute.

Also sometime angular strips down some attribute from the html string you are rendering.

You can create a pipe for displaying the html as it is

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({ name: 'securehtml' })
export class SecureHtml {
    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(html) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

and in html

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlstring | securehtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [innerHTML]="description"></div>
```

in ts file put data in description it will work